# Convert Access table to .ini file with schemas via Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ini

I was wondering if this is something thats possible: currently I use this clickonce application to generate .ini files of access tables, I started learning vb.net not too long ago and I was wondering if I can replicate this utility via a vb.net form/app? Since currently not all the users in my company can use this utility for whatever reason by upper management and I looked around this site and other places, I found resources on how to create schema .ini files but what if the schemas are already in an sql table?

So for example each type of client has a code and schema type in our sql tables with "pick up locations", we use this in the click once app where I can select the access db, the table, and the location to drop off the created .ini file.

Currently in the sql, I have all the schemas in the schema table that has 3 different schemas and we tie the clients to one of these with each schema having different field order, length, type etc.

I want to be able to create a form and the user would be able to input the location of the access db and the table to be converted, then the client name (from a drop down) and based on the client the vb.net app would generate the correct schema ini file in the location for that client. Is this possible? I just dont want to keep looking into something if its not something achievable. Any information is greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: You have a lot of different DB tags listed that probably do not apply.  a schema.ini is used to define the data layout of a CSV file.  *That* shema is used by OleDB to import the data to a DataTable or send to an Access db.  Not sure if that is what you are talking about.

Comment: I apologize which tags should I remove? and oh yes after we generate it the IT load that file through an app in vb sorry I am still learning, I thought I could use that for the app I am trying to create so would I need to create another schema for the generating of the ini file?

Comment: A schema describes something - usually a DB or a table in a DB.  OleDB uses that concept in the Text Driver for describing CSV data using `schema.ini`.  As such your post is very confusing.  Maybe if you described what you are trying to do (rather than *how*) it would be clearer